# Get declarative dojo datagrid by ID

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm having trouble accessing a declaratively created datagrid by ID, so that I can set its datastore.

Here's my code, but tree is coming back as *undefined*.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.3/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table data-dojo-id="myTree" dataType="dojox.grid.TreeGrid" summary="This is a test">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th field="a" width="200px">A</th>
                    <th field="items" aggregate="sum" itemAggregates="count">
                        <table>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th field="name" width="200px">Name</th>
                                    <th field="count" width="200px">Count</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </body>
    <script>
        require(["dijit/registry", "dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore"], function( Registry, ReadStore ) {
            var store = new ReadStore();
            var tree = Registry.byId("myTree");
            console.log(tree);
            // tree.setStore( store );
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several issues leading to your problem.

- `dataType` is not a thing; you want `data-dojo-type` (you're probably confusing it with the deprecated `dojoType`)
- Setting `data-dojo-id` creates a global variable, not an ID for Dijit's registry; set `id` instead
- You're never actually running `dojo/parser` on the document, either, so even with these issues addressed, you won't end up with an actual widget

Here is a fixed example:

```
<body>
    <table id="myTree" data-dojo-type="dojox/grid/TreeGrid" summary="This is a test">
        ...
    </table>
</body>
<script>
    require([
        "dojo/parser",
        "dijit/registry",
        "dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore",
        "dojox/grid/TreeGrid"
    ], function(parser, registry, ReadStore) {
        parser.parse();
        //var store = new ReadStore(...);
        var tree = registry.byId("myTree");
        console.log(tree);
        // tree.setStore( store );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I get the following error with your example: dojo/parser::parse() error TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined {stack: (...), message: "Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined"}parser.js.uncompressed.js:89

Comment: I had assumed you were on at least Dojo 1.8.  If you're on something earlier, try data-dojo-type="dojox.grid.TreeGrid" as you originally had, rather than the module ID syntax I used.